# Requests from docker container in Google Cloud Run Service to Google Cloud SQL takes up to 2 minutes

Tags: database, spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

Im using the Google Cloud Run service to host my Spring application in a docker container. The database is running in the Google SQL service. My problem is that the requests from the application to the database can take up to 2 minutes. See the [Google Cloud Run log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qovy1.png)  (the long requests are painted yellow). And here's the [Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNqLq.png) and [Docker Compose File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NktOQ.png)

The database is quite empty, it contains about 20 tables but each contains only few rows, so no request is bigger than few kB. And to make it more strange, after re-deploying the application the requests are fast again. But after few minutes, hours or even after a whole day the requests slow down again. When I start the application on my local machine the requests are always fast (to my local SQL and Google SQL instance), never had any slow connection. All actions within my application that doesn't require any DB request are still fast and takes only few ms.

Both services are running in the same region (europe-west) and CPU usage of the run service is never higher than 15%, of the Google SQL never above 3%. The Google SQL uses 1 CPU and 3.75GB, the Google run service has 4GB RAM and 2CPUs. But increasing the power of the Google Run Service and Google SQL doesn't improve the request latency. Google Cloud SQL is using MySQL 5.7 (like my local DB).

And after seeing the logs only warnings are shown in the [filtered Google SQL log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpI0o.png) (I really dont know why this happens). Additionally here are my DB connection settings in the [Spring config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7WM7.png). But I dont think this has any impact, the config works perfect when connecting my local application to my local SQL instance or to the Google SQL instance.

But maybe one of you has an idea?

Comment: Can you set a timeout on your database connexion with Spring? let say, 10s, and see if it's better or not.

Comment: It's not just you Markus, every so often for no discernible reason the latency between Cloud Run and Cloud SQL will just go into insanely high numbers for no reasons. On the 19th we had a random spike in latency for about 15 minutes. I'm just as curious as you are in regards to getting this resolved.

Comment: Did you already try using a different connection method to the database? E.g. going through a vpc connector or a public ip instead of using the native cloud run sql connector.

Comment: @Stefano Via a public IP it works normally but I pay for the Google Cloud Run service so it should work via it too. That's not acceptable by Google that they slow down the connection randomly (or what ever causes this problem). It seems to be only a problem between Google Run/App Engine and Google SQL

Answer (score 3):

While not a real answer, there is a bug filed at Google that is tracking the issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186313545

This is really hurting our customers experience and makes us loose trust in the service quality of cloud run. Even more so if there is no feedback from Google to know if they are even addressing the issue.

---

##### Edit:

The issue now seems to be resolved, according to the interactions in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186313545

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue tracker. Never thought that would be a wide-ranged problem. I hope Google is willing to fix that! Sounds like that affects a lot more projects ...

Comment: Looks like the issue is resolved. If it is not working for you I'll recommend you to post it on the [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) directly.